# Migrate from BuildMaster to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, buildmaster

Need help on moving from BuildMaster to Jenkins.

We have around two hundred applications hosted and have been using BuildMaster, now the company has proposal to move to Jenkins because of some additional benefits we get.

I am new to Jenkins, need help how can we get this migration process easier.

Comment: Curious, what are the additional benefits for the company? I understand certain users might prefer one tool or the other, but an organization willing to spend a great deal of resources converting 200+ build plans must be getting some kind of ROI out of it.

Comment: We want to give control to Dev team in lower environment for deployments.

Comment: @JohnRasch - main benefit is that you can avoid license issue, Jenkins being open source you do not need to worry about license at all.